# Filtrar ao selecionar uma checkbox

Tags: cakephp

### Preciso fazer um filtro onde é mostrado certos dados quando selecionado alguma(s) checkbox.

**Por exemplo:**

Foi marcado o checkbox "`Aguardando embarque`" e "`Recebido`", então devera mostrar uma lista em uma tabela que contenham os `Status` dos checkbox selecionados.

**Checkbox:**

```
Aguardando embarque | Embarcado | Recebido | Em análise | Aguardando aprovação
--------------------|-----------|----------|------------|---------------------
          X         |           |     X    |            |
```

---

**Saída:**

```
Número Ose |  Nome  | Status da Ose | Perfil Usuário
-----------|--------|---------------|----------------
     65    |  Admin |  Aguardando   |  Administrador
           |        |   Embarque    |                
-----------|--------|---------------|----------------
     69    |  Admin |   Recebido    |  Administrador
```

Caso eu não tenha sido claro, por favor comentem para que eu possa lhes fornecer mais informações sobre o que eu preciso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solução:

Na `Controller` eu faço um filtro para cada `Checkbox`, no caso do exemplo abaixo farei somente três:

### **Controller**

```
  $this->Filter->addFilters(
          array(
              'filter1' => array(
                   'Filtro1.descricao' => array(
                       'operator' => 'ILIKE',
                       'value' => array(
                           'before' => '%',
                           'after' => '%'
                        )
                    )
               )
               'filter2' => array(
                   'Filtro2.descricao' => array(
                       'operator' => 'ILIKE',
                       'value' => array(
                           'before' => '%',
                           'after' => '%'
                        )
                    )
               )
               'filter3' => array(
                   'Filtro3.descricao' => array(
                       'operator' => 'ILIKE',
                       'value' => array(
                           'before' => '%',
                           'after' => '%'
                        )
                    )
               )
          )
   );
```

Depois inicializo as variáveis que serão utilizadas no `foreach` abaixo:

```
$conditions = array();
$vFiltro = array();
$filtro1 = '';
$filtro2 = '';
$filtro3 = '';

foreach ($this->Filter->getConditions() as $chave => $valor) {
    if ($valor != '%0%') {
        if ($chave == 'Filtro1.descricao ILIKE') {
            $filtro1 = $valor;
        }
        if ($chave == 'Filtro2.descricao ILIKE') {
            $filtro2 = $valor;
        }
        if ($chave == 'Filtro3.descricao ILIKE') {
            $filtro3 = $valor;
        }
    }
}
```

Depois se os filtros não estão vazios eu adiciono cada filtro na variável de condições `$conditions` para fazer a paginação.

```
if (!empty($filtro1)) {
    $conditions[] = "Filtro1.descricao ILIKE '" . $filtro1 . "'";
} elseif (!empty($filtro2)) {
    $conditions[] = "Filtro2.descricao ILIKE '" . $filtro2 . "'";
} elseif (!empty($filtro3)) {
    $conditions[] = "Filtro3.descricao ILIKE '" . $filtro3 . "'";
} else {
    $conditions[] = "";
}
```

Após fazemos a paginação para mostrar os itens que queremos.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'fields' => array('Ose.id', 'user_nome', 
                      'Status.descricao', 'Group.descricao'),
    'joins' => array(
        array('table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => ['User.group_id = Group.id'],
        ),
        array('table' => 'statuses',
            'alias' => 'Status',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => ['Status.id = Ose.status_id_destino'],
        ),
        array('table' => 'statuses',
            'alias' => 'Filtro1',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => ['Filtro1.id = Ose.status_id_destino'],
        ),
        array('table' => 'statuses',
            'alias' => 'Filtro2',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => ['Filtro2.id = Ose.status_id_destino'],
        ),
        array('table' => 'statuses',
            'alias' => 'Filtro3',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => ['Filtro3.id = Ose.status_id_destino'],
        ),
    'condition' => array($conditions),
    'order' => array('Ose.id' => 'asc')
);
```

Acima tem o alias `Ose` e o alias `User`, não faço o relacionamento deles por aqui, pois já foi feito na `Model`.

Após eu seto os valores de paginação.

```
// Aqui é definido quais status serão exibidos
$i = [1, 2, 3];
$this->set(
    'ose', $this->paginate(
        'Ose', array(
            'Ose.ativo' => 't%', 
            'Ose.status_id_destino' => $i
        )
    )
);
```

### Então na `View` fazemos o seguinte:

**View**

```
 <?php 
      echo $this->Search->create();
      echo $this->Search->input(
                      'filter1', array(
                            'id' => 'filter1', 
                            'type' => 'hidden'
                       ));
      echo $this->Search->input(
                      'filter2', array(
                            'id' => 'filter2', 
                            'type' => 'hidden'
                       ));
      echo $this->Search->input(
                      'filter3', array(
                            'id' => 'filter3', 
                            'type' => 'hidden'
                       ));
 ?>
```

E finalizamos com o `Snippet` abaixo onde ao clicar na `Checkbox` desejada o valor é adicionado no campo de texto exemplificado no `Snippet`, mas na verdade será incluído no campo `input` acima, conforme é feito no `CAKEPHP`.

```js
function filtro1(value) {
  var filter = document.getElementById('filter1');
  if (document.getElementById('1').checked) {
    filter.value = value;
  }
}

function filtro2(value) {
  var filter = document.getElementById('filter2');
  if (document.getElementById('2').checked) {
    filter.value = value;
  }
}

function filtro3(value) {
  var filter = document.getElementById('filter3');
  if (document.getElementById('3').checked) {
    filter.value = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js "
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="text" name="filter1" id="filter1">
<input type="text" name="filter2" id="filter2">
<input type="text" name="filter3" id="filter3">

<table border='1px' celspacing='0' colspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Aguardando embarque</th>
    <th>Embarcado</th>
    <th>Recebido!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" onclick="filtro1(value)" id="1" value="Aguardando embarque">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" onclick="filtro2(value)" id="2" value="Embarcado">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="filter3" onclick="filtro3(value)" id="3" value="Recebido">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" />
```